# "'module' object has no attribute 'Gridspec'" despite calling help(gridspec) revealing the Gridspec class

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I run the python console and do

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
```

I see that the matplotlib version is 1.2.1.

If I do `help(gs)` I see the Gridspec class.

However the following code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
g = gs.Gridspec(1,1)
```

produces the error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Gridspec'`

Why can't I create a new Gridspec object?

Answer (score 5):

You meant to type `g = gs.GridSpec(1,1)`. The "s" in "Spec" is capitalized.

Comment: Worst use of an hour of my life ever. Thanks for the solution. Don't program when you're tired.