# Serialize / Unserialize using json.dumps/loads gives AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to capture payment result info from Amazon FPS, which comes in 2 forms:

- User redirected to originating server with GET and query string parameters
- Amazon sends POST to originating server with matching parameters

I can't guarantee which request will reach the server first, so I store the first in the DB by serializing either `request.GET` or `request.POST` using `json.dumps` and then attempt to load it later on using `json.loads` for comparison with the other request:

Initial request:

```
type = request.META['REQUEST_METHOD']
sub_req = SubscriptionRequest()
params = getattr(request, type)
serialized_params = json.dumps(params)
if type == 'GET': sub_req.client_params = serialized_params
if type == 'POST': sub_req.server_params = serialized_params
sub_req.save()
```

Followup request:

```
stored_params = json.load(sub_req.server_params if type == "GET" else sub_req.client_params)
```

Error:

```
  File "/var/www/test.com/htdocs/apps/subscription/services.py", line 147, in subscription_request_check_or_store
    stored_params = json.load(sub_req.server_params if type == "GET" else sub_req.client_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 274, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Json.load() reads from a file. Use json.loads() to parse a string.

Comment: D'oh! I just read that on another question and looked at my code and thought I saw an 's'! Must have been imagining things :S. Thanks :)

Comment: @DanH - yours was the second question in a row with an ['s' problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050713/module-object-has-no-attribute-gridspec-despite-calling-helpgridspec-rev). Must be something in the water.